# Problem passing value of environment variable inside a Makefile to a docker run command

Tags: docker, makefile

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an environment variable during testing but it does not work when run from inside a Makefile. It works fine when I type the docker command directly in the shell. What is wrong with this code:

Makefile:

```
run:
    docker run -e DOC_PATH='test' my-python-app:1.0
```

The problem is when I read the environment from inside the app, I get a KeyError meaning it could not be found.

python code:

```
import os
print(os.environ['DOC_PATH'])
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir app
ADD src/* /app

WORKDIR "/app"

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Comment: It works on my side, your infomation is not enough to expose the error.

Comment: What is in the image?  Does that same `docker run` command work any differently outside a Make context?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I don't expect it differently outside a Make context.  I merely want to use a make file to run it simply and repeatedly during development.